# Physical applications of Chebyshev's equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

As reported by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_equation), Chebyshev's equation is the second order linear differential equation
$$(1-x^2) {d^2 y \over d x^2} - x {d y \over d x} + p^2 y = 0 $$
where $p$ is a real constant.

Has equation above physical meaning? That is, is it used to model some physical phenomena?

Comment: see also here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145177/what-physical-phenomena-are-modelled-by-chebyshev-equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the similarity of **Chebyshev's equation** with [Legendre's equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDifferentialEquation.html), it does not occur often in physical sciences or engineering, however, solutions of Chebyshev's equation are of importance in **numerical analysis** such as solution to partial differential equations, smoothing of data etc. While, on the other hand, its close associate Legendre's equation occurs quite often in areas such as **electrodynamics** and **quantum mechanics**, among others.

**Main Source:** Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering: A Comprehensive Guide - By K. F. Riley, M. P. Hobson, S. J. Bence

Answer (score 0):

Chebyshev's equation can be used to generate polynomials that could serve as mathematical model to approximate some  observed physical phenomena.